# Nested view backbone

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, backbone.js, mobile

I'm try to do a nested view. Backendview call another view Listpostview but doesn't work.I've inserted a console.log in a a nested view Liastpostview to see if it's called but it's never printed.

Below code of external view:

```
var BackendView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: "p",

    events: {
      "touchend": "goToDetails"
    },

    template: Handlebars.compile(template),

    initialize: function () {

      this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
      this.model.bind("destroy", this.close, this);
    },

    render: function (eventName) {


    console.log(this.model);


    var list=new ListPostView({model:this.model});
    list.render();

      return this;
    },


  });

return BackendView;

});
```

This is code of ListPostView called by view above:

```
var ListPostView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: "ul",
    id: "list",

    template: Handlebars.compile(template),

    initialize: function () {
        console.log(this.model);
      this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    },

    render: function (eventName) {
    console.log("dddd"+this.model);<---this console.log will never called!?
      $(this.el).empty();
      _.each(this.model.models, function (ad) {
        $(this.el).append(new SinglePostView({
          model: ad
        }).render().el);
      }, this);
      return this;
    }
  });

return ListPostView;

 });
```

and finally code of view called by last view above:

```
var SinglePostView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: "li",

    events: {
      "touchend": "goToDetails"
    },

    template: Handlebars.compile(template),

    initialize: function () {
        //console.log(ad);
      this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
      this.model.bind("destroy", this.close, this);
    },

    render: function (eventName) {
      var ad = this.model.toJSON();
      ad.cid = this.model.cid;
      $(this.el).html(this.template(ad));
      console.log(this.template(ad));

      return this;
    },


  });

return SinglePostView;

 });
```

Comment: Nobody can help me please?

Comment: Is `BackendView#render` called anywhere? And some suggestions: (1) If the view's model is a collection, use `this.collection` to avoid confusion. (2) Use `this.collection.each(...)` instead of `_.each(this.collection.models, ...)`. (3) Use `this.$el` instead of `$(this.el)`. (4) Use `on` instead of `bind`.

Comment: @muistooshort (4) is still a bad idea as it will lead to memory leaks, use `this.listenTo(this.model,` instead.

Comment: @Andrew But you'll still have to call [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) or [`stopListening`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-stopListening), `listenTo` just makes it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're using the `list` variable in your `BackendView` render method after calling render on it.

I see that `list.render()` is called but that doesn't insert the `list.$el` element in the DOM anywhere. The first thing I would test is from your render method in `BackendView` call `this.$el.append(list.$el)`